# Firebase performance via Cocoapods generates missing GoogleAppMeasurement on Jenkins

Tags: ios, firebase, jenkins, firebase-performance

I have successfully added Firebase Analytics via cocoapods. After adding firebase performance sdk over it, the archive process on jenkins is throwing error. Any suggestions can help me sail through.

```
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\Copy \XCFrameworks /../../Path_to_build_folder/QARelease-iphoneOS/GoogleAppMeasurement-framework.build/Script-......sh
```